# YouTube API from V2 to V3 migration

Tags: youtube-api

I'm still using old V2 api and now i get https://youtube.com/devicesupport.

My current request is:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{username}/uploads?alt=jsonc&max-results=15&v=2

**There is no authentication required to make that call**

Question:
Any idea how to achieve the same with new Google V3 API? I check documentation but  didn't found answer for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble migrating from V2 to V3 of YouTube API - can't list uploads of a channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759841/trouble-migrating-from-v2-to-v3-of-youtube-api-cant-list-uploads-of-a-channel)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with V3 api. I think you can't access videos informations without authentication anymore, but you don't need to use an OAuth to get a snippet from some video or search. I was searching a simple solution for my app, because I just want to request title, thumb and descriptions.

The new url will be:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videosid={VIDEO_ID}&part=snippet&key={YOU_API_KEY}

You need to access google developers console, enable youtube api and your public access key - on credentials (API KEY), so they can relate your app to all requests.

And I found this example in PHP if you need to parse JSON result:
http://www.leenooks.com/php/parsing-youtube-v3-json-with-php-examples.html

I'm still don't know all the limitations of V3, I was using V2 too, but maybe for uploads, or more control for youtube accounts you'll have to use OAuth.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Here's all the informations you can get from the url 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

ex: &part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status"