# Migrate youtube api code version 2 to version 3

Tags: youtube-api

I used youtube api version 2 in my php code. How I can migrate my code to version 3 quickly?
Should I get new developer key? I used google developer key before: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/  but now I can't open this page, I see 502. That’s an error.

[image]

My youtube API 2 code:

```
require_once("Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php");
require_once("Zend/Gdata/HttpClient.php");
require_once("Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php");
require_once("Zend/Gdata/App/HttpException.php");
require_once('Zend/Uri/Http.php');

$authenticationURL = 'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
    $username = $CFG->videoboard_youtube_email,
    $password = $CFG->videoboard_youtube_password,
    $service = 'youtube',
    $client = null,
    $source = 'VideoBoard',
    $loginToken = null,
    $loginCaptcha = null,
    $authenticationURL);

$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, 'VideoBoard', NULL, $CFG->videoboard_youtube_apikey);

$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

$accessControlElement = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element(
    'yt:accessControl', 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', ''
);
$accessControlElement->extensionAttributes = array(
    array(
        'namespaceUri' => '',
        'name' => 'action',
        'value' => 'list'
    ),
    array(
        'namespaceUri' => '',
        'name' => 'permission',
        'value' => 'denied'
    ));

$myVideoEntry->extensionElements = array($accessControlElement);

$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource($from->fullpatch);
$filesource->setContentType($data->type);
$filesource->setSlug('slug');
$myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);

$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($from->author);
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($from->author);
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Education');
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('videoboard');

$uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';

try {
    $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
    echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();

    $DB->delete_records('videoboard_process', array('id' => $data->id));
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

    $DB->delete_records('videoboard_process', array('id' => $data->id));
}

$itemidyoutube = $newEntry->getVideoId();

if (!empty($itemidyoutube)){
    $DB->set_field($table, "itemyoutube", $itemidyoutube, array("id" => $item->id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation). Usually, [502](http://winaudit.org/guides/youtube-error/youtube-error-502.html) error may be caused by windows system files damage. The corrupted system files entries can be a real threat to the well being of your computer. There is also a reported [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/zTj_iIoeJm0) before that there is a temporary issue with the sign up 
server, which suggested to access it at `http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html`. Here's a [blog](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939) for possible solutions.

You may also check with these related SO threads:

- [Trouble migrating from V2 to V3 of YouTube API - can't list uploads of a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759841/trouble-migrating-from-v2-to-v3-of-youtube-api-cant-list-uploads-of-a-channel)
- [YouTube API from V2 to V3 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913591/youtube-api-from-v2-to-v3-migration)